# Difficulty narrowing down XPath of checkbox

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am practicing some Selenium on the following website:

www.automationpractice.com

I have a couple basic tests I have started below:

```
import unittest
from webdriver import Driver
from values import strings
from pageobjects.homescreen import Homescreen


class TestHomeScreen(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = Driver()
        self.driver.navigate(strings.base_url)

    def test_home_screen_components(self):
        home_screen = Homescreen(self.driver)
        home_screen.logo_present()

    def test_choose_dress(self):
        home_screen = Homescreen(self.driver)
        home_screen.choose_dress()

    @classmethod
    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.instance.quit()
```

Those tests are being read from the following:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from values import strings


class Homescreen:

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def logo_present(self):
        self.logo = WebDriverWait(self.driver.instance, 10).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((
                By.ID, "header_logo")))
        assert self.logo.is_displayed()

    def choose_dress(self):
        self.dresses = WebDriverWait(self.driver.instance, 5).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((
                By.XPATH, '//*[@id="block_top_menu"]/ul/li[2]/a')))
        self.dresses.click()
        self.casual_dresses = WebDriverWait(self.driver.instance, 10).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((
                By.XPATH,'//input[@type="checkbox" and @id="layered_category_9"]')))
```

the test_home_screen_components passes fine, but the test_choose_dress fails.  I have narrowed it down it is failing on the final XPATH, which is a checkbox for "casual dresses". It can't be found.  I have confirmed in Chrome that this XPATH is valid:

```
self.casual_dresses = WebDriverWait(self.driver.instance, 10).until(
     EC.visibility_of_element_located((
         By.XPATH,'//input[@type="checkbox" and @id="layered_category_9"]')))
```

on the following page:
http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_category=8&controller=category#/categories-casual_dresses

So I am not sure what the problem is.  Maybe I am missing something because it is embedded?

Also I know I need to add some Try/Except to my code eventually as well, I am just starting out with this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

```
EC.visibility_of_element_located
```

with

```
EC.presence_of_element_located
```

to be able to handle required checkbox

Comment: Thank you! I thought it was an issue with my xpath itself...I didn't even think about the selenium call itself.  That worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Please scroll the element **casual dresses** into view and then check the presence of the element

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", self.casual_dresses)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the *url* `http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_category=8&controller=category#/categories-casual_dresses` moving forward as you are trying to invoke `click()` on the element so instead of `visibility_of_element_located()`  method you need to use [**`element_to_be_clickable()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) method as follows:

```
self.casual_dresses = WebDriverWait(self.driver.instance, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@class='checked']/input[@class='checkbox' and @id='layered_category_9']")))
```

Comment: Thanks!  This solution works as well, and will be good when I need to click on the checkbox as well.